# How to implement groupByUntil in apache-flink?

Tags: apache-flink

Some reactive frameworks has `groupByUntil` function. It is allow to group elements by key and remove it after specific event or time interval (i.e. [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/groupbyuntil.md) description from RxJS).

As I can see apache-flink doesn't have such function out of the box. Can anybody explain me how to implement such function in apache-flink?

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a look at Flink's time windows? Windows are used to group elements of a stream, for example by time and key.

You can define a tumbling time window as follows:

```
val s: DataStream[(Int, Long)] = ...

val r: DataStream[(Int,Long)] = s
  .keyBy(_._1)
  .timeWindow(Time.minutes(5))
  .minBy(2)
```

This will partition the stream be the first `Int` element (_._1) and create every five minutes a window for each key to group the elements. On each window, the `minBy` function is applied to select the element with the smallest `Long` value.

You can also define sliding windows, count windows, or implement you own windowing logic using Triggers and Evictors. The window evaluation function (`minBy` in the example) can also be a custom implementation.

You should check the [DataStream documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/streaming_guide.html) for more details.